# Finding statistical significance between two binary tests

Tags: statistical-significance, binary-data

I have two sets of data. One with a sample size of 82 with 53 "hits" and 29 "Misses." And a second sample of 105 with 67 "hits" and 38 "misses"

Given that the second set of data is a control, is there a way to show that the results of the first data set are or are not statistically significant?

Thanks in advance, It's been a while since I took a stats course and googling for the answer left me confused.

Comment: Is the null that the population proportion of hits is the same for the two groups? Then you have a two-sample proportions test (sometimes two-sample binomial proportions test); it might also be done as a chi-square.

Comment: I believe so, the null would be that proportion of hits is the same. I am hoping that the first sample has more hits and isn't just chance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would start by stating things more formally, e.g. (with no prior information):

> The null hypothesis is that these two samples come from the same population. The alternative is that they come from different populations where one really has more "hits".

A simple and traditional approach would be [Fisher's exact test](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fisher%27s_exact_test).

Wiki should allow you to calculate it manually for your data.

If using `R` you could do something like this:

```
> cm1 <- matrix(c(53, 67, 29, 38),
                nrow = 2,
                dimnames = list(c("first", "control"), c("hits", "misses"))) 
> addmargins(as.matrix(cm1), c(1,2))
        hits misses Sum
first     53     29  82
control   67     38 105
Sum      120     67 187
> fisher.test(cm1)
```

Gives `p=1` meaning probability of your data given the null is very high (suggests that first group v. unlikely to be different from control).

You can also do

```
fisher.test(cm1, alternative="greater")
```

meaning

> The null hypothesis is that these two samples come from the same
>   population. The alternative is that the first comes from a different
>   population which has more "hits" than the second.

... but it's still `p=0.52`.

Now there are other methods but most will accept that it's unlikely that there's any great difference between `53/82 = 65%` and `67/105 = 64%`

Comment: The two sample proportions test was quite similar, though I did it two tailed.

Comment: Really nice answer from dardisco, I don't have enough reputation so I will leave the link to python reference here https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.stats.fisher_exact.html